# TypeError: Class constructor DiscordPagination cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: discord, discord.js

Whenever I try to run the =help command I get the error "TypeError: Class constructor DiscordPagination cannot be invoked without 'new'". I'm trying to use  https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js-pagination
Given below is my code :

````
const Discord = require ('discord.js')

module.exports = {
  name: 'hhelp',
  description:' new help command',

  async execute (message, args) {

    const fun = new Discord.MessageEmbed ()
      .setTitle ('Fun!')
      .addField (`8-ball`,' Tells the answer to your question')
      .addField (`Meme`,' Displays some of the finest memes on Reddit')
      .addField (`Dank-meme`,' Displays some of the dankiest memes on Reddit')
      .addField (`Boop`, 'Boops a user the same kind the command is , USELESS!')
      .addField (`Mod`,' Ever heard of a discord mod ? :D')
      .setTimestamp ()

      const DankMemer = new Discord.MessageEmbed ()
      .setTitle ('Dank-Memer!')
      .addField (`heist`,'Unlocks a channel for a **specific** role mentioned')
      .addField (`Over`, 'Locks the channel for the role mentioned')
      .setTimestamp ()

      const Utility = new Discord.MessageEmbed ()
      .setTitle ("Utility")
      .addField (`Covid`, 'Tells the covid cases for a specific country or the entire world combined')
      .addField (`Ping`, 'Tells the latency of the bot')
      .addField (`Invite`, 'Gives the invite link for the bot')
      .addField (`Vote`, 'Gives the top.gg voting link for the bot')
      .addField (`Avatar`, 'Gives the avatar of a user')
      .setTimestamp ()

      const pages = [
        fun,
        DankMemer,
        Utility
      ]

      const emojiList = ["⬅", "➡"]

      const timeout = '120000'

      pagination (message, pages, emojiList, timeout)

      

    
  }
} ```
````

Comment: Error is self explanatory. Like any Class, you have you initialize it with the keyword `new`

Comment: @Elitezen ,  how do i do that? sorry i am a bit new , if possible please edit the code. Thank you

Comment: It's only natural that know you JavaScript before trying to use a JavaScript library. Refer to the Classes guide by MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Comment: @Elitezen , thanks i read it and have fixed the problem